# Repurposing PWM output for D- of USB

Tags: microcontroller, usb, stm32, embedded

I'm currently designing a self-powered PCB with a STM32L432KCU6 MCU on it. I want to use USB, but D- is already used for a different purpose.

According to the datasheet, D- and D+ have to be connected to PA11 and PA12. For PA12, this is no problem as this pin is still free. However, I'm using PA11 to drive a small 8 mA LED that is controlled via PWM. There is no free pin to which I could assign this function instead.

**My question:**
Is it possible to repurpose PA11 from a PWM output to D- once VBUS is detected?

Here the datasheet of the MCU:

https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/stm32l432kb-956275.pdf

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhDb1n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I hope you also have a debug serial interface on your board; if not and you have not proven your USB software on an EVB first you may have a very frustrating process of getting things going.  If you *do* have a debug serial interface, that would be a much more sensible thing to multiplex with the LED.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I have a debug serial interface.

Comment: In addition to what's said in the posted answer, you obviously can't have 10 ohm in series with the LED. I take it that's a typo? When you re-design the board, ensure that the LED is driven from a pin which can source sufficient current. Some STM32 can source lots of current on GPIO, pick the right one for your project.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply: No, you can not.

A USB interface is a high speed serial interface with strict impedance rules. The tracks have to be routed side-by side having an impedance close to 90 ohm.

You can **not** make a tap and route that somewhere else or connect other components to one (or both) of them.

So you have to find a different solution.

Comment: … and since you say "I'm currently designing a board": well, connecting that LED there was a design mistake that's relatively easy to fix. Re-design that part of the board.

Comment: If you just need more GPIO for LEDs, switches, etc., I2C or SPI based I/O expander chips are easy to use.

Comment: It is definitely a bad idea, that said for a one off *personal use* hack USB can sometimes tolerate things far out of spec, so I'd hesitate to say that there are no circumstances under which it could work, but definitely not for a product and even for personal use there needs to be a fallback plan like cutting off the LED.  Also D- needs to be released faster than it can confuse the speed detection.  There's almost certainly a better place to connect the LED.

Comment: It is possible od course. Place mosfet very close to the path. It will not change significantly enough the impedance of the track but if the vusb is detected will disconnect the led from it. I have tested it on FS & HS devices. Works without any problems